# DateDiff in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am using following SQL query to find difference between two datetime fields, this query returns time in hours, but i want time in HOurs,minutes and seconds Collectively.

```
Convert(decimal(18,2),(select datediff(hh,JobScreen.[DateTimeOn], 
                       JobScreen.[DateTimeOff]))) as [ActualHrs]
```

Please suggest options.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So multyiply the hours with 60 for minutes, and 3600 for seconds?

Comment: It's better to include sample data and desired results in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it collectively, why cast it as `decimal(18,2)` that expresses only one value?

```
JobScreen.[DateTimeOff] - JobScreen.[DateTimeOn] as TimeSpan
```

This will work for time spans that are under a day (24 hours).

Example:

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @dt2 datetime
set @dt = '20121202 11:43:54'
set @dt2 = '20121202 13:23:23'
select @dt2 - @dt TimeSpan,
       convert(char(8), @dt2 - @dt, 8) TimeSpanVarchar

|           TIMESPAN | TIMESPANVARCHAR |
-----------------------------------------
| 1900-01-01 01:39:29|        01:39:29 |
```